# Nginx coflicting name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate

I created new server, then added same domain as on my previous server, that i deleted.
So i got this warning after `sudo nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain.name" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "api.domain.name" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

The problem is, I cant change my domain name, because it's academic project.

My default file in sites-available:

```
server {

        listen 80;

        server_name api.B0rDiplom.students.nomoredomains.monster;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/b0rdiplom.students.nomoredomains.monster/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/b0rdiplom.students.nomoredomains.monster/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {

        listen 80;

        server_name B0rDiplom.students.nomoredomains.monster;

        root /home/diplom/Front;

        location / {

         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/b0rdiplom.students.nomoredomains.monster/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/b0rdiplom.students.nomoredomains.monster/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

How can I fix it? Or should i anyway create new domain?

Comment: Use `sudo nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Make sure that these `server` blocks and `server_name` directives appear exactly once.